# How to pass image batches as locals to profile.runctx?

Tags: python, unit-testing, profiling, faster-rcnn

I want to send a batch of images to `profile.runctx`  Ex

```
profile.runctx('print (inference(image_batch,batch_size)); print()',
               globals(),
               {'image_batch':'how to send image batch?','batch_size':128})
```

I have a function called `inference` which accepts a sequence image batches as input. How to pass a sequence of images as parameter in `profile.runctx`?

Answer (score 1):

You've left many details out the example code in your question, but here's a guess:

```
import profile


def inference(image_batches, size):
    for i in range(size):
        print('image_batches[{}]: {}'.format(i, image_batches[i]))
    return 42


image_batch = ['image1', 'image2']
batch_size  = 2

profile.runctx('print(inference(image_batch, batch_size)); print()',
               globals(), locals())
```

Alternatively you could do something more explicit like this:

```
profile.runctx('print(inference(image_batch, batch_size)); print()',
               globals(), {'image_batch': ['image1', 'image2'],
                           'batch_size': 2})
```